# How to maintain reference equality during serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have an issue with serialization in C#/.NET where if I serialize in one stream multiple references to a same object, these references are no longer equal after deserialization. I am using default binary serialization. The code that trips me is:

```
Check ck1 = new Check();
Check ck2 = new Check();
ck1.Numbers = new int[] { 11, 12, 13 };
ck2.Numbers = ck1.Numbers;
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(ck1.Numbers, ck2.Numbers));
FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\deleteme-check3.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryFormatter oos = new BinaryFormatter();
oos.Serialize(fs, ck1);
oos.Serialize(fs, ck2);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
fs = new FileStream("d:\\deleteme-check3.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
oos = new BinaryFormatter();
Check ck3 = (Check)oos.Deserialize(fs);
Check ck4 = (Check)oos.Deserialize(fs);
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(ck3.Numbers, ck4.Numbers));
```

The declaration is

```
[Serializable]
class Check
{
  public int[] Numbers = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
}
```

When I run this code I get `True` and `False`. I am looking for features that I can use that would give me `True` and `True`.

Note #1: I've checked around and seen references to using `DataContractSerializer` and `MarshalByRefObject`, but I don't see how to apply these features to this problem;

Note #2: I'm aware that I can write my own custom serialization logic but I'd like to avoid that and instead use default serialization. If I use default serialization in Java, for instance, I would get `True` and `True` in this scenario and I am looking for similar tools in .NET.

Comment: By definition the original and the deserialized copy are different objects and different references.

Comment: @EliArbel Not sure I understand your question but they need to be the same (second true) because they were the same (first true). And can you elaborate your proposed solution for using IObjectReference?

Comment: @Oded I am pretty sure you have not understood the question. I am not comparing objects before serialization with objects after deserialization. I am comparing two objects after deserialization!

Comment: @Mishax - They are still different objects, in different addresses. They are _different_ references. If you want these to have _value type semantics_, you need to override `==`, `Equals`, `GetHashCode` etc...

Comment: @Oded I am already aware that they are different objects in different addresses, because I checked that with ReferenceEquals. The question is since this is the default behavior, how do I get custom behavior so that the references would be equal. Incidentally would you mind showing me how you would override `==`, `Equals` etc on an array type?

Comment: @Mishax you cannot change the equality behavior of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply isn't going to happen. Any reference-preserving semantics are only valid for a single call to `Serialize` / `Deserialize`. To get what you want, you would need to use some kind of wrapper, i.e.

```
[Serializable]
public class HazTwo {
   public Check First {get;set;}
   public Check Second {get;set;}
}
```

then serialize:

```
var obj = new HazTwo { First = ck1, Second = ck2 };
oos.Serialize(fs, obj);
```

and deserialize:

```
var newObj = (HazTwo)oos.Deserialize(fs);
var ck3 = newObj.First;
var ck4 = newObj.Second;
```

Reference identity will not ever be preserved between separate calls to either `Serailize` or `Deserialize`, with the slight exception of `IObjectReference` - but since arrays don't implement `IObjectReference`, this is rather moot.

Frankly, I suspect you would be best advised to either:

- use a wrapper object, so that only a single `Serialize` / `Deserialize` call is in play for the scope where references need to be preserved
- find an alternative design that does not rely on this

I should also add the footnote that I usually advise people against over-use of `BinaryForamtter` - I've seen far too many people lose data or get into a mess, typically when they iterate between versions of their code. It is not very amenable to change.

Comment: This is useful; It seems in Java the design was to preserve reference semantics within a single OutputStream, and .NET the design was to limit this to the scope of a single invocation of Serialize. I do not know what is the reasoning behind the two approaches but it's good to remember the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
It is not possible to do the comparison that you want because ReferenceEqual is really meant to check wheter it is the same object. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Unlike the Equals method and the equality operator, the
>   ReferenceEquals method cannot be overridden. Because of this, if you
>   want to test two object references for equality and are unsure about
>   the implementation of the Equals method, you can call the
>   ReferenceEquals method. However, note that if objA and objB are value
>   types, they are boxed before they are passed to the ReferenceEquals
>   method.

So if you want to have the ReferenceEqual the only way you can do it as I described below.

Original Post

On the first check you get true because of these statements

```
ck1.Numbers = new int[] { 11, 12, 13 };
ck2.Numbers = ck1.Numbers;
```

The second line makes that ck2 refers to the same object as ck1.

On deserialization you do

```
Check ck3 = (Check)oos.Deserialize(fs);
Check ck4 = (Check)oos.Deserialize(fs);
```

What you do here is create two new objects and ck3 and ck4 refer to different objects. To get the same results as before serialization you shuold do

```
Check ck3 = (Check)oos.Deserialize(fs);
Check ck4 = ck3;
```

Here an new object ck3 is created and ck4 = ck3 ensures that both refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks Marco, but that does not help me. I do not want ck4 and ck3 to refer to the same object, I want the properties of the two distinct objects, that were referenceequals before serialization, to be referenceequals after serialization.